# Implement RESTful service in Java EE using J2EE Preview runtime in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

These are the steps I followed to create a simple RESTful Web Service with Jax-RS in Eclipse IDE for Java EE.

- Create a new Dynamic Web Project (Name : TestExample)

  - Select target runtime as J2EE Preview
  - Dynamic web module version : v3.1
  - Configuration type : custom with following project facets

    - Dynamic Web Module : v3.1
    - Java : v1.8
    - JAX-RS (REST Web Services) : v2.0
  - Check "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor"
- Under Java Resources (in Project Explorer) create a new package (`my.test.example`) and a class under the same (`TestService`)
- Import external jar file [`javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxwsrsapi20jar.htm) and add it to build path to resolve `javax.ws.rs` import error
- `TestService.java`

  ```
  package my.test.example;

  import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
  import javax.ws.rs.GET;
  import javax.ws.rs.Path;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

  @Path("/MyTestService")
  @ApplicationPath("/resources")
  public class TestService extends Application {

      // http://localhost:8080/TestExample/resources/MyTestService/sayHello
      @GET
      @Path("/sayHello")
      public String getHelloMsg() {
          return "Hello World";
      }
  }
  ```
- `web.xml`

  ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>TestExample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
  ```
- Run the project

Opening this url : `http://localhost:8080/TestExample/resources/MyTestService/sayHello` in a browser returns this :

```
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI:    /TestExample/resources/MyTestService/sayHello
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    default
```

**Console Output**

```
Starting preview server on port 8080

Modules:
  TestExample (/TestExample)

2020-05-21 11:45:45.175:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1815ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2020-05-21 11:45:45.894:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.27.v20200227; built: 2020-03-02T14:40:42.212Z; git: a304fd9f351f337e7c0e2a7c28878dd536149c6c; jvm 1.8.0_171-b11
2020-05-21 11:45:48.219:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /TestExample, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2020-05-21 11:45:48.289:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-05-21 11:45:48.289:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-05-21 11:45:48.299:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-05-21 11:45:48.425:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7d907bac{TestExample,/TestExample,file:///C:/.../wip/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/TestExample/,AVAILABLE}{C:/.../wip/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/TestExample}
2020-05-21 11:45:48.489:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6ed3ef1{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-05-21 11:45:48.504:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @5150ms
```

The expected output would be `Hello World`. What am I missing here?

The steps followed are based on a tutorial on Youtube : [Java EE Tutorial #18 - RESTful Web Services with Jax-RS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmMdLW92hBA).

**Eclipse Version** : 2020-03 (4.15.0)

**Note**: I got it to work with GlassFish Runtime, however would still like to know why it doesn't work with J2EE Runtime.

Project Structure in Eclipse :

[image: project structure]

Comment: Try this url once: Opening this url : http://localhost:8080/resources/MyRestService/sayHello

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka It returns `Error 404 - Not Found 
No context on this server matched or handled this request.`, I think I am missing serverlet mappings in web.xml for resources, but I am not sure

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424103/java-rest-webservice-display-name

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka It doesn't help

Comment: I don't think your service and application should be the same class. Could you separate them? (Make sure the service is in the same package or a child package of the package that your application lives in)

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling As I have mentioned in the question, the same project structure works perfectly fine with other runtimes like GlassFish

Comment: What is the context root of the project?

Comment: @Edgar Context root is TestExample

Comment: Can you share your source code?

Comment: @Edgar I believe you can find it in the question

Answer (score 0):

## Quick

- Remove `/` from `@ApplicationPath("/resources")`
- web.xml is not required

## Explanation

According to this samples:

- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/path-annotion-resource-mapping.html
- https://www.connect2java.com/webservices/jax-rs-applicationpath-annotationno-web-xml-example-in-jersey/

The argument for `@ApplicationPath()` is a simple word, without `/`

Try with:

```
@Path("/MyTestService")
@ApplicationPath("resources")
```

Instead (/resources)

```
@Path("/MyTestService")
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
```

And try to use correct maven versions to avoid the web.xml usage.

Comment: The quickfix doesn't help. I have mentioned in the question, it works as expected for GlassFish Runtime but doesn't for J2EE Preview Runtime. I am using eclipse IDE to follow the steps mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the project structure, J2EE Preview runtime does not include its own JAX-RS implementation. However, in GlassFish Runtime a reference implementation of JAX-RS is already included.

I did the following to get it to work with J2EE Preview runtime :

Instead of doing this step

> Import external jar file javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar and add it to build
> path to resolve javax.ws.rs import error

I converted the eclipse project to a maven project and in `pom.xml` added the following dependency<sup>1</sup>

```xml
<!-- v2.25.1 conforms to JAX-RS v2.0 spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In `web.xml`<sup>2</sup>, I added this

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <!-- Define servlet class to be used-->
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <!-- Configuring Jersey container Servlet or Filter to use package scanning-->
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.test.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Map servlet to URL with pattern "/resources/*"-->
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Note**

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731512/10155936), Servlet 3.0 onwards `web.xml` is optional. Annotations can be used instead. However, as seen in this question [Why won't the preview server in Eclipse respect my @WebServlet annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48001280/10155936) annotations doesnot seem to work with J2EE runtime, hence the use of `web.xml`.

**References**

<sup>1</sup>[Jersey Dependencies for Servlet based server-side application](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#servlet-app-general)

<sup>2</sup>
[Servlet-based Deployment](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2) , [How to deploy a JAX-RS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2072295/10155936)